# PHP multi dimensional array search by conditions

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am developing a financial web application I am really stuck with this issue.

I need to search with conditions and return the array if the condition is true..

I know the multi-dimensional array search, but I did't get any idea for this. For example :

```
if array[0][7] > array[0][8] && array[0][12] < array[0][15]
```

Please suggest me the solution

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( 
    [0] => 54452 
    [1] => 'KSB'
    [2] => 'INE999A01015'
    [3] => 'EQ' 
    [4] => 'Ksb Limited' 
    [5] => -0.70 
    [6] => -0.10 
    [7] => 662.90 
    [8] => 663.60 
    [9] => 669.35 
    [10] => 678.25 
    [11] => 651.55 
    [12] => 7874 
    [13] => 676.91 
    [14] => 690.93 
    [15] => 703.61 
    [16] => 664.23 
    [17] => 650.21 
    [18] => 637.53 
    [19] => 623.51 
    [20] => 2530 
    [21] => 32.13 
    [22] => 825.00 
    [23] => 539.00 
    [24] => 665.89 
    [25] => 631.37 
    [26] => 616.65 
    [27] => 610.14 
    [28] => 615.89 
    [29] => 656.25 
    [30] => 680.74 
    [31] => 60.71 
    [32] => 60.71 
    [33] => 13.62 
    [34] => 29.39 
    [35] => -38.97 
    [36] => 129.47 
    [37] => 2019-09-26 
    [38] => 27632 
  ), 
  [1] => Array ( 
    [0] => 53772 
    [1] => 'ASPINWALL' 
    [2] => 'INE991I01015' 
    [3] => 'EQ' 
    [4] => 'Aspinwall And Company Limited' 
    [5] => -10.50 
    [6] => -7.74 
    [7] => 127.45 
    [8] => 137.95 
    [9] => 135.60 
    [10] => 144.50 
    [11] => 112.60 
    [12] => 9583 
    [13] => 143.76 
    [14] => 160.08
    [15] => 175.66 
    [16] => 128.18 
    [17] => 111.86 
    [18] => 96.28 
    [19] => 79.96 
    [20] => 5108 
    [21] => 53.30 
    [22] => 214.80 
    [23] => 112.60 
    [24] => 135.17 
    [25] => 137.13 
    [26] => 137.46 
    [27] => 136.86 
    [28] => 137.59 
    [29] => 143.00 
    [30] => 153.89 
    [31] => 39.41 
    [32] => 39.41 
    [33] => -0.90 
    [34] => 37.96 
    [35] => -58.05 
    [36] => -361.91 
    [37] => 2019-09-26 
    [38] => 26324 
  ) 
)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly  is stopping you?

Comment: I want to know how to search  with conditions in multi-dimensional array

Comment: What is wrong with your approach mentioned in your example? `if array[0][7] > array[0][8] && array[0][12] < array[0][15]` You just need to convert this to php syntax

Comment: function search_sg_dma($array, $pre_close, $dma_value, $close_price) 
{ 
    $results = array(); 

    if (is_array($array)) 
    { 
        if (isset($array[0][$pre_close]) < $array[0][$dma_value] &&  $array[0][$close_price]  > $array[0][$dma_value]) 
            $results[] = $array; 

        foreach ($array as $subarray) 
            $results = array_merge($results, search_sg_dma($array, $pre_close, $dma_value, $close_price)); 
    } 

    return $results; 
} This is the code I have wrote .. But I am getting Error

Comment: From where are these data getting plotted into array. And what exactly you want to achieve from array. Can you please explain it in better way.

Comment: @Nakshathraglobal please consider editing your question and add the code for `function search_sg_dma` so that your question is more clear and the code is relevant. Doing so you'd be helping other members of to better understand your problem so that they can provide you help with your problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a try to following code and make necessary changes according to your need

```
function search_sg_dma($array, $pre_close, $dma_value, $close_price){

...

    $result = array();
    for( $i = 0; $i < count( $array ); $i++ ) {
        if ( $array[$i][$pre_close] < $array[$i][$dma_value] && $array[$i][$close_price] > $array[$i][$dma_value] ) {
            $result[] = array[$i];
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Glad that you got solution. If it's my answer please mark it accepted answer to help others to get idea. Thanks!